# column data cannot be null c# mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I was creating a program that can insert audio into mysql database(i am using mediumblob data type) but when i click insert button it showed an error "column data cannot be null". Here is my code :

```
private void buttonBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "WAV Audio Files|*.wav|M4A Audio Files|*.m4a";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBoxBrowse.Text = ofd.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void buttonSimpan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(Program.konek);
        OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("insert into audio(data) values(@voice)", con);
        byte[] stream = File.ReadAllBytes(@textBoxBrowse.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(stream.ToString());
        if (stream.Length > 0)
        {
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@voice", stream);
            con.Open();
            int result = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result > 0)
                MessageBox.Show("insert done");
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Comment: ODBC doesn't support named parameters. Try to change `@voice` into `?`

Comment: Also, why don't you use the MySQL data provider?

Comment: i am using odbc because it support creating report in vs 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN [OdbcParameter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter.aspx)

> When CommandType is set to Text, the .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC does not support passing named parameters to an SQL statement or to a stored procedure called by an OdbcCommand. In either of these cases, use the question mark (?) placeholder. For example:

So change your query

```
OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("insert into audio(data) values(?)", con);
byte[] stream = File.ReadAllBytes(@textBoxBrowse.Text);
    MessageBox.Show(stream.ToString());
    if (stream.Length > 0)
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("voice", stream);
        con.Open();
        int result = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (result > 0)
            MessageBox.Show("insert done");
        con.Close();
    }
}
```